# Add special character to persp plot

Tags: r, graphics, label, expression

I am using the persp() function to make a 3d plot.

I just want to add a greek letter or math expression to the axes labels, but that has proven to be difficult. I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
rm()
library(graphics)#for 3d plot

beta_grid=c(1,2,3,4)
alpha_grid=c(1,2,3,4)
z=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),4)


labNames <- c('xLab','yLab')
xlab <- bquote(.(labNames[1]) ~ x^2)
ylab <- bquote(.(labNames[2]) ~ y^2)
persp(alpha_grid, beta_grid, z,theta=45, phi=45,xlab = xlab, ylab=ylab)
```

I have also tried this more obvious solution:

```
persp(alpha_grid, beta_grid, z,theta=45, phi=45,main=expression(x^2+gamma),xlab=expression(x^2),ylab=expression(gamma))
```

but as you can see, this only works for the tile of the graph, not for the axes (see figure below).

[image]

Any help on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you cannot use expressions in the axis labels:

> **xlab, ylab, zlab** titles for the axes. *N.B. These must be character strings; expressions are not accepted. Numbers will be coerced to character strings.*

However, all is not lost. You can get superscript digits and Greek letters via Unicode escape sequences:

```r
xlab <- "x\u00b2"
ylab <- "\u03b3"

persp(alpha_grid, beta_grid, z, theta = 45, phi = 45, 
      xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, cex.lab = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked! From now on I think I will use unicode for my labels: it seems more practical than using expression() in combination with paste(). The only problem I saw with unicode, is that some of the letters look kind of funny: the gamma looks like a y.

Comment: @AngryR11 that's just the font. If you change it it a serif font a may look better.

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron. But how would we write, for instance, the gamma in this font: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D6C4  I have tried writing xlab="\u1d6c4", but I get b4, instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the docs describe the limitation to character strings for `xlab` and `ylab`.  An alternative is to use `rgl::persp3d` instead.  It doesn't accept `bquote(.(labNames[1]) ~ x^2)`, but it is fine with `expression(x^2)` and similar:

```r
library(rgl)

beta_grid <- c(1,2,3,4)
alpha_grid <- c(1,2,3,4)
z <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),4)

persp3d(alpha_grid, beta_grid, z,theta=45, phi=45,
        main=expression(x^2+gamma),
        xlab=expression(x^2),
        ylab=expression(gamma),
        front = "lines",
        back = "lines")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You'll probably want to customize it a bit; the default view is kind of ugly.

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting an error when trying to load the rgl package: "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL)
  error: OpenGL is not available in this build"

Comment: @AngryR11:  This is a different issue.  `rgl` does ask for some OS libraries to be present, but will build without them.  It's supposed to do this somewhat transparently, so that if they aren't present it will load but won't display within R:  you'll need to use the `rglwidget()` function to save the display to be displayed in a browser (or RStudio, which has one built in).  But apparently in your case, something went wrong, and the "transparent" part wasn't.  If you want to follow up, post an issue to https://github.com/dmurdoch/rgl/issues .